# PowerBI Refresh Through Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory

I have developed a Pipeline according to the post "https://www.moderndata.ai/2019/05/powerbi-dataset-refresh-using-adf/#comment-2610".

However I keep getting an error "Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - 'Unauthorized', message - '' in the CALL DATASET REFRESH WEB ACTIVITY.

I haven't registered the Security Group for API access using the Service Principals. Could this be causing an issue ?.note(I am not the PowerB admin)

Not sure what is causing this issue.
When I execute the same thing through a Powershell script it works fine. Not sure why it is not working through the azure datafactory.

Comment: Yes, just from the error message, you don't have the permission to access/refresh the PowerBI. The post you reference also said you must has the request permission.

Comment: Thank you @leon Yue, that helps . I have requested for the access .

Comment: Hi @Rachael DSouza,  you're welcome.  If my answer is helpful for you,  hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from the error message, you don't have the permission to access/refresh the PowerBI. The [post](https://www.moderndata.ai/2019/05/powerbi-dataset-refresh-using-adf/#comment-2610) you reference also said you must has the request permission.

Please request for the access and test again.