# PowerBI Refresh Through Azure Data Factory using API

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, powerbi-desktop

I have developed a Pipeline according to the post https://www.moderndata.ai/2019/05/powerbi-dataset-refresh-using-adf/#comment-2610

However I keep getting an error "Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - 'Unauthorized', message - '' in the CALL DATASET REFRESH WEB ACTIVITY.

Comment: @RachaelDSouza with reference to your earlier Q: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202752/powerbi-refresh-through-azure-data-factory) did that issue fix after registering the Security Group for API access using the Service Principals (or) is that issue caused due to some other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting below error

> "Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - 'Unauthorized',
> message - '' in the CALL DATASET REFRESH WEB ACTIVITY.

Because you **don’t have permission to access PowerBI**.

Please check permissions to access PowerBI.

You can also follow this article for [Refreshing a Power BI Dataset in Azure Data Factory](https://datasavvy.me/2020/07/09/refreshing-a-power-bi-dataset-in-azure-data-factory/)

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is only to "Refresh" a Power BI Dataset, you don't necessarily have to use the API.

You could trigger a 'Logic App - Workflow' using 'Web' activity in ADF, which will initiate the refresh of the dataset.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.